# Swift generic method issue while passing model class to nested methods

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, generics, closures

I have a json response that is in the format of

**ServerResponse -> ResponseData -> data array**

```
 struct ServerResponse<T: Codable>: Codable {
    let methodName: String
    let responseCode: Int
    let responseMessage: String
    let responseData: ResponseData<T>

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case methodName = "methodName"
        case responseCode = "responseCode"
        case responseMessage = "responseMessage"
        case responseData = "ResponseData"
    }
}

    struct ResponseData<T: Codable>: Codable {
        let order: Int
        let data: [T]

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case order = "order"
            case data = "dataArray"
        }
    }

    struct Post: Codable {}
    struct Comment: Codable {}
    struct Comment: Codable {}
```

In my response data can be any kind of codable class array  like Post , comment , Users etc.

I have created some generic methods to parse the response

```
 func fetchGenericData2<T: Codable>(data: Data, completion: @escaping (T) -> ()) {
    self.fetchGenericData(data: data, completion: { (result:ServerResponse<T>) in
        print(result.responseData.data[0])
       // completion([result.responseData.data])
    })

}
func fetchGenericData<T: Codable>(data: Data, completion: @escaping (T) -> ()) {
    do {
        let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        print(responseObject)
        completion(responseObject)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }
}
```

I am calling the method by passing my required codable class

```
 self.fetchGenericData2(data: data, completion: { (response:[User]) in
                    print(response)
                })
```

Currenly my generic model is not reaching to the final method so it does not know what kind of class it is.

If i send the final model directly that it works fine like the following:

```
 self.fetchGenericData(data: data, completion: { (response:ServerResponse<User>) in
                        print(response.responseData.data)
                    })
```

but in this case i have to send ServerResponse class which is not abstracted.

How can i format my methods so that i just have to call a method with my final model name and i get the model array directly for eg: something like this:

```
 self.fetchGenericData(data: data, completion: { (response:[User]) in
                        print(response)
                    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the data type to T so that it will be decoded what is being passed,

```
struct ResponseData<T: Codable>: Codable {
    let order: Int
    let data: T

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case order = "order"
        case data = "dataArray"
    }
}
```

Now it will work as expected when you are calling it as below,

```
 self.fetchGenericData(data: data, completion: { (response: ServerResponse<[User]>) in
                    print(response)
                })
```

But if you want the syntax where you want to pass only the data type then you have to update your generic method as below,

```
func fetchGenericData<T: Codable>(data: Data, completion: @escaping (T) -> ()) {
    do {
        let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(ServerResponse <T>.self, from: data)
        print(responseObject)
        completion(responseObject)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }
}
```

This will allow you to call as below,

```
self.fetchGenericData(data: data, completion: { (response: [User]) in
                    print(response)
                })
```

Comment: Thank you kamran. You are a genius.
I think you meant like following as the model is coming inside responsedata->data


func fetchGenericData<T: Codable>(data: Data, completion: @escaping (T) -> ()) {
        do {
            let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(ServerResponse <T>.self, from: data)
            print(responseObject)
            completion(responseObject.responseData.data)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            
        }
    }

Also will it also work even if data can be either array or dictionary ?